# How to select all records in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code `

```
User::first()->attachPermission($permission);
```

which select first user in table user, but I want to select all user from user table. I create

```
User::get()->all()->attachPermission($permission);
```

but this not working

Comment: Use `all()` or `get()`, but not both. Without any qualifiers, they do the same thing. When you add `all()` after `get()`, it's actually running [`all()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-all) on the collection

Answer (score 2):

Just simply use

```
  User::all();
```

OR

```
  User::get();
```

Answer (score 0):

To attach permissions, you just need to add them to the iteration using either `all()` or `get()` as shown by @aynber and @Telexx:

```php
$users = User::get();

foreach($users as $user){
    $user->attachPermission($permission);
}
```